# Making UIAlertView a popOverView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have a UIAlertView, but I would like it to display like this:

[image]

Not on the bottom like this:

[image]

Please Note: I will only have text, not any buttons.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)myButton:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertController *alertCtrl = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Hello" 
                 message:nil 
                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    [self presentViewController:alertCtrl animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I probably need something like a UIPopOver, with a arrow direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement a [`UIPopoverController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/index.html), and make it look like an `UIAlertView`. The popover is going to be a `UIViewController`, which you have to customize so it looks just like what you want.

Here's a good tutorial on both: [Introduction to UIActionSheet and UIPopoverController](http://www.appcoda.com/uiactionsheet-uipopovercontroller-tutorial/)

Comment: I'm pretty new to objective C, can please you guide me a little bit more?

Comment: sorry my tutorial link was wrong. I fixed it now. Read the tutorial and you'll learn how to do it. ;)